# Unable to run python script with shebang from /usr/local/bin

Tags: python-3.x, cron, linux-mint

I have a python script saved to /usr/local/bin with

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

at the top and a chron job to run it 30 seconds after reboot and it's not working. When I try to run ./usr/local/bin/check_bios.py I get

```
bash: ./usr/local/bin/check_bios.py: No such file or directory
```

When I copy it to my home directory it works fine. When I execute it with

```
python /usr/bin/local/check_bios.py
```

it runs fine. I have

```
alias python="python3"
```

in my bashrc file, but I don't think that is what's causing this behavior. I tried adding /usr/bin/local to my path, but cron wouldn't use the path as far as I can think of. Does anyone know why the cron job won't execute and whay ./usr/bin/local/check_bios.py would throw an error? I'm on Linux Mint 20.2 if that helps at all.

Comment: Why do you have a ```.``` at the beginning of the python script path?   When you run it manually, you don't have it.

Comment: @ewong It tells the system to execute the program/the program is executable. It then looks and the "shebang" line tells the system what to execute the script with. The same can be done with a bash script by using #!/bin/bash and then chmod +x ing the file. If I copy it to the home directory ```./check_bios.py``` works fine and so does ```python check_bios.py```

Comment: Yes, but does it have to be the 1st character of the path?  Shouldn't there be a space between ```.``` and ```/usr/local/bin/check_bios.py```?

Comment: Huh. Guess I've never tried to execute a script using ./ that I wasn't actually in a directory with. Did some testing and F me, you're right. I understand that . means current directory. So I'm guessing my misconception was that I thought it meant "run" when it really was, "from the current directory in case where you are isn't in your PATH" If you want to throw that into an answer I'll mark it. Thank you @ewong. Been thinking on this/searching for a few days now. Yeah, I'm slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the error:

```
bash: ./usr/local/bin/check_bios.py: No such file or directory
```

the cron job was looking for the check_bios.py script in the `./usr/local/bin` path.

From that, I guessed that the cron job was:

```
? ? ? ? ? ./usr/local/bin/check_bios.py
```

where ? represents the time values (deliberately left them as ? since they weren't mentioned in the post, nor are they relevant to the issue).

I believe it should be:

```
? ? ? ? ? . /usr/local/bin/check_bios.py
```

Comment: It should be: ? ? ? ? ? /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/check_bios.py